# What is the intended use case for app auth and app users?

Tags: box-api

I am trying to understand what is the intended use case for app auth and app users. Im basically thinking about building an app that would use Box to store data of users that would subscribe to our service. Our service would allow each user to access and view their data.

If I have an account that basically owns the data of all the subscribed users, can I use the enterprise access token as a base for authentication while using the user account token to restrict the user to only viewing the data from their specific sub directory. Or do I have to have a unique account with its own api key for every user?

I hope this makes sense. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Auth and App Users -- which is officially called [Box Platform](https://developers.box.com/box-platform/) -- is essentially a [white-labeled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-label_product) version of Box. I think of it this way: "Box" as we know it is software-as-a-service. It offers a web app, mobile apps, and all the trimmings. Box Platform is the platform layer upon which the SaaS is built, providing API-based management of users/content/comments/collaborations/etc. With Box Platform you have a walled garden in which you can build apps that leverage all the features of the APIs, but are not otherwise "Box apps."

> I'm basically thinking about building an app that would use Box to store data of users that would subscribe to our service. Our service would allow each user to access and view their data.

This is an appropriate use case. With Box Platform you will be the owner and administrator of a Box enterprise and all the accounts and data contained within.

> If I have an account that basically owns the data of all the subscribed users, can I use the enterprise access token as a base for authentication while using the user account token to restrict the user to only viewing the data from their specific sub directory. Or do I have to have a unique account with its own api key for every user?

I think it's generally cleanest to create unique accounts for each user as opposed to giving users a special subdirectory in the admin account. From there you can use the App Auth workflow to get an access token specific to that user.

Comment: I would like to thank you for clearing that up for me.